# LWC Get value from cell in datatable selected rows

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lightning-events

I'm trying to determine the value of one of the cells in a selected row in an LWC datatable, but can't find how to do this.

```
   <lightning-datatable
    key-field="Id"
    data={accounts}
    columns={columns}
    onrowselection={getSelectedRecord}>
  </lightning-datatable>
```

After selecting the rows another button submits them to an apex class for processing. I need to check whether the row contains a birthdate, however, but can't seem to find a way to check the value in the DOB column. How would I do this? Everything works fine, but the alert doesn't - if I leave that in I get a [Cannot read property '0' of undefined]. I put the alert in just to see whether I could access the value. I need to exclude all rows where DOB is null.

```
const columns = [
  {
    label: "Name",
    fieldName: "nameUrl",
    type: "url",
    typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: "Name" }, target: "_blank" }
  },    
{
    label: "Birthdate",
    fieldName: "PersonBirthdate"
},
.....

 getSelectedRecord(event) {
   this.selectedRecords = event.detail.selectedRows;
 }
 ....... After selecting the rows a button click picks ups the selected rows
 - the button fires the event below.

submitVerification(event) {
if (this.selectedRecords.length < 1) {
  this.dispatchEvent(
    new ShowToastEvent({
      title: "Refresh grid",
      message: "You have not selected any rows",
      variant: "error"
    })
  );
  } else {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedRecords.length; i++) {
    this.selRows.push(this.selectedRecords[i].Id);
    //alert(this.selectedRows[i].PersonBirthdate);
  }
```

Comment: As such there is no visible flaw in your code. Suggest you to improve this question with some more specifics *(for example, are you not able to access the specific field value or the event is not getting fired?)*.

Comment: Please paste your full code. From your code and the requirements the place where you need to perform the business logic is `getSelectedRecord(event)` as this event only contains all the row information.

Comment: I've updated the question with some more info. The events fire no problem, just the alert doesn't work as I get the error [Cannot read property '0' of undefined]. The push just above it works perfectly.